# Django Websocket getting slow as the connected users increases

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, consumer, channel

I am using Django Channels to send messages to the frontend. and the frequency of the messages is one message per second, everything works fine when I am working on local but on production where I used Nginx, Gunicorn and Daphne to host the server, the connection to the websocket happened after 2-3 attempts, and after the webscokets get connected the messages started coming really slow. Is this issue is related to the server or with the code ?

consumer.py

```
class MyConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'Live Message'
        self.error_code = 4011
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.close(self.error_code)

    async def send_live_data(self, event):
        data = event.get('value')

        additional_msg = get_additional_msg()
        data['additional_msg'] = json.dumps(additional_msg, default=default)

        try:
            await self.send_json(data)
        except Exception as e:
            await self.disconnect({'code': self.error_code})
            await self.close(self.error_code)
```

message.py

```
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
async def send_data():
    try:
        await (channel_layer.group_send)('Live Message', {
        'type': 'send_live_data',
        'value': {'live_message':json.dumps(message)}})
    except:
        print("Error while sending message ...\n", traceback.format_exc())

class MyWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
    
    def run(self):
        print('Worker is running .....')

        while True:
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            loop.run_until_complete(send_data())
            loop.close()

            time.sleep(1)

MyWorker().start()
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: Can you add your consumer that has the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I added the code, you can check.

Comment: Thanks, the consumer helps. Can you show how/where the messages are sent once a second? Does the `get_additional_msg` function hit the DB and can you show that too?

Comment: `get_additional_msg` is the function of the third party library which providing a data.

Comment: I suspect your issue is the function `get_additional_msg`, if it's performing some API call or DB access then each call is blocking every connection - if you remove the call does the performance improve and not degrade with each added connection?

Comment: as I said before `get_additional_msg` is a third party library function, which returning dataframe, which have new data every seconds so should I call this function here or remove it from here and update any global dictionary and access the dictionary there ?

Comment: I will test the suggestion you provided, will try to test the performance after removing the function and let you know will this working or not.